# Editing feature class without creating separate output?

Tags: arcpy, feature-class, personal-geodatabase

I have a feature class in my geodatabase and I would like to convert multi-parts to single-parts using the following syntax:

```
MultipartToSinglepart_management (in_features, out_feature_class)
```

Is there a way to edit the feature class itself without creating a separate out_feature_class?

---

I am using a personal geodatabase and was wondering if there is a way to edit the feature class itself rather than creating an output and replacing the result. I think using an in-memory workspace works best.

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by @AlexTereshenkov](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245788/editing-feature-class-without-creating-separate-output#comment385311_245788) for an enterprise geodatabase:

> A pretty easy way to do this would be to make your outputs an
>   in_memory feature class, then truncate your source feature class, and
>   then append your output feature class back to it.

and if you are doing it in another type of geodatabase like a file geodatabase you could always output to an in-memory workspace, delete the original and then copy back.